# Why is the derivative Df(p) defined to $ \in \Lambda^1 (\mathbb{R}^n) $, or how is it a 1-form?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms

I know that obviously the differential operator $D$ would be a differential form through the word differential. But in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* he defines a $k$-form $w$ as $w(p) \in \Lambda^k (\mathbb{R}^n_p) $.

$ w(p) = \sum_{i_{1}<i_{2}<\dots<i_{k}} w_{i_{1}i_{2}\dots i_{k}}(p) \cdot[\phi_{i_{1}}(p)\wedge \phi_{i_{2}}(p)\wedge\dots\wedge \phi_{i_{k}}] $,
where the $ \phi_{i} $ are the dual basis to the tangent space vectors. From this definition how does he get that for a scalar function $f$,   $Df(p)  \in \Lambda^1 (\mathbb{R}^n) $ ?
Since $ \Lambda^k (\mathbb{R}^n_p) $ is a set of alternating tensors, does that mean that $Df(p)$ is also an alternating tensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $1$-form is just a smooth choice of a linear functional on the tangent space at every point in the manifold. Note that every linear functional is alternating, but it doesn't really mean anything, since all permutations on a set of one vector are trivial.

Likewise, the derivative of a function is a linear functional on every tangent space. For $v\in T_pM$, $df_p(v)$ is a number, equal to the derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$.

In general, a $k$-form is indeed an alternating tensor that eats $k$ vector field and returns a function. A $1$-form thus eats one vector field and returns a function. Every tensor of type $(1,0)$ is alternating, obviously.